# Цикл FOR удаляет все строки, при проверки на схожесть строк

Tags: c#, desktop

Нужно чтобы при проверке удалились те строки, которых нет в `globalDataMySQL` и есть в `globalDataExcel`, здесь получается так, что удаляются все строки из `globalDataExcel`.
Понимаю, что это из-за того, что условие выполняется при любом неправильном значении и соответственно цикл не успевает проверить всю таблицу. Но как это дело исправить — I don't know.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < globalDataTableExcel.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i].RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Count; ++j)
                        {
                            if(globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString() != globalDataTableMySQL.Rows[j][0].ToString())
                            {
                                globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i].Delete();
                                ++minusSlov;
                                break;
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: В введите логическую переменную для определения нахождения такой строки. А Нето у вас получается строка может и равна кому-то но следующей в цикле не равна и происходит удаление

Comment: @AzizUmarov как это реализовать? Честно говоря, отдал целый день этому участку кода, меняя его как только в голову придет, буду безмерно благодарен...

Comment: @AzizUmarov я понимаю, что речь идет про булеву переменную, не знаю просто как здесь ее применить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутренний цикл должен выглядеть так:

```
bool found = false;
for (int j = 0; j < globalDataTableMySQL.Rows.Count; ++j)
{
    if(globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i][0].ToString() == globalDataTableMySQL.Rows[j][0].ToString())
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }   
}
if(!found)
{
    globalDataTableExcel.Rows[i].Delete();
    ++minusSlov;
}
```

Comment: теперь вообще не удаляет

Comment: Ну, тут надо ещё подумать. По-хорошему ещё и "на ходу" нехорошо удалять из коллекции, по которой итерируемся.

Comment: буду рад, если поможете с реализацией, честно говоря, уже сил нет, весь день отдал на это...

Comment: ```globalDataTableMySQL``` и ```globalDataExcel``` это таблицы типа DataTable

Comment: Заметил исправление в вашем коде, помогло, благодарю! Не поверите, убил целый день на эти несчастные строки, столько нервов...

Comment: @byte_ Да, я что-то не всё сходу сообразил, несколько раз менял код )